# Identify these two large, colorful dragonflies in Taiwan?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Here are two dragonflies that I photographed today in Hsinchu county Taiwan. They are both quite large, with a body length of about 5 or 6 cm.

I often see them in the same pond or nearby marshy area. They seem pretty confident and are easy to photograph as long as you don't make a big commotion.

The arrows were drawn for my other question [Why do dragonflies have these special little spots on their wings?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/95609/27918)

Is it possible to identify these two species? I can break them out as separate questions if necessary; I don't want to flood the site with "identify this dragonfly" questions.

The first is jet-black everywhere except for a robins-egg blue powdery coloration along the top side of the first two-thirds of it's abdomen. It's wings, like most but not all dragonflies, are transparent.

The second has some amount of red almost everywhere; its eyes and thorax are dull red and it has bright red patches on each segment of its abdomen. Notably its wings are solid opaque red, except for the furthers 1 cm which is transparent. The tiny "special spots" on the tips of each wing are a particularly bright shade of red!

[image]

[image]

Comment: one more: [Identify this dragonfly with orange body and orange wings?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/95612/27918)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this species is [Orthetrum triangulare](https://eol.org/pages/131385) commonly known as blue-tailed forest hawk. It is an Asian fresh water dragon fly species.

As you mentioned that the dragonfly had a bluish hue, it became clear.

[image]

The other one looks like Neurothemis ramburri, commonly known as red perch [Reference](http://defworld.freeoda.com/Species%20Details/Neurothemis%20ramburii.html)

> Neurothemis is a genus of dragonflies in the family Libellulidae. Most Neurothemis species are red in color.
> Neurothemis ramburii (Brauer, 1866) is distributed from Sundaland to New Guinea. There are records from Peninsular Malaysia, **Taiwan**, the Andaman Islands, Sumatra, Java, Borneo (Sarawak, Sabah, Brunei and Kalimantan), the lesser Sunda islands, the Philippines, the Bismarck islands and New Guinea. It is a widely distributed and common species that thrives in disturbed habitats.[image]

Comment: Wow that was fast, *thank you!*

Comment: @uhoh you may accept the answer if you are satisfied for the future references

Comment: indeed, thank you for the reminder. I generally wait a week or more to allow for review by other readers and the posting of additional answers, and a week has now passed.